Unable to install all modules. - vmware 17.5.2 - secure boot disabled
I have a problem updating Vmware Player modules. Previously I used to use mkubecek's Github repo to download and compile modules, now they seem to be unavailable for Player 17.5.2.
In the log I see the line Skipping BTF generation for /tmp/modconfig-Cz0CkS/vmnet-only/vmnet.ko due to unavailability of vmlinux which I tried to follow. A lot of people recommend disabling secure boot in BIOS in case of a similar error, and for some it worked, not for me though. I have secure boot disabled.
Here is the log I uploaded to Pastebin, any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.
Oh, BTW, I'm on Linux MInt 22, kernel version 6.8.0-44-generic, if that helps.

Do the files /usr/lib/vmware/settings, /home/junglized/.vmware/config exist, with appropriate content?  What's useful in /tmp/vmware-junglized/vmware-2952.log? Did you even read your logvomit before posting it?

@waltinator I don't know what logvomit is. I only checked log which has been displayed as a reference when error popped up. I don't know what's useful in /tmp/vmware-junglized/vmware-2952.log. I f I knew all of that I wouldn't post a question here but probably resolved the issue myself  :)
